# Strange behavior when assigning a VBA array to formulas of an excel range

Tags: arrays, performance, vba, excel

This is strange... Someone has some knowledge or can figure out why is this happening?

In the past, I was able to assign an array of formulas to an Excel range (*Example of fast assignment:* `Range("A1:A1000") = ArrayOfFormulas` ). It was working fine and *FAST* (***very*** *FAST*) compared to assign cell by cell (*Example cell by cell: `Range("A" & i).Formula=ArrayOfFormula(i)` inside a loop. Is slow!*).

I'm working with Excel 2013 now, and when trying to assign the formulas stored in an array of strings to an excel range it doesn't work (The excel shows the formulation but not the calculation as per left part of the picture below) an unfortunately I cannot retrieve old code to compare. For example the following code shows "=1+2" instead of "3" in the range A1 to A1000.

```
Sub AssignFormulas_1()
    Dim i as Long
    Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String
    For i = 1 To 1000
         FORML_ARRAY(i, 1) = "=1+2"
    Next i
    Range("A1:A1000").Formula = FORML_ARRAY  '<- Don't work as formula
                                             '   It put the value!
End Sub
```

However, when I don't use the array of formulas it work fine (all cells shows "3" instead of "=1+2" as per the right part of the picture below). Here the code:

```
Sub AssignFormulas_2()
    Dim i as Long
    Dim FORML_SINGLE As String
    FORML_SINGLE = "=1+2"
    Range("A1:A1000").Formula = FORML_SINGLE '<- works ok, not practical for my
                                             '   real life case as I need 
                                             '   different formula for each cell.
End Sub
```

The following code work also well (In this case I assign formulas cell by cell, so is more flexible but sloooowly for large formulas).

```
Sub AssignFormulas_3()
    Dim i as Long
    Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String
    For i = 1 To 1000
         FORML_ARRAY(i, 1) = "=1+2"
         Range("A1:A" & i).Formula = FORML_ARRAY(i, 1) '<- works ok, but slowly
    Next i
End Sub
```

The pictures with the output of all above code:

[image: Example of result wrong (left) and correct (right)]

---

Note: The cells were properly formatted as number, not text!

Comment: No 2013 to check, but I found [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837104.aspx) that might be helpful.

Comment: @Passerby, thank you, but FormulaArray() is intended for something else. It is for working with Matrix or Array of Excel formulas, but not for Array of VBA. Using FormulaArray() you will get in your cell the formula `{=Sum(A1:A3)}` and not `=Sum(A1:A3)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, When would this EVER be practical? Your spending time filling an array with formula, to write formulas to a range that will then have to be calculated?!?! Why not Simply fill a range with formulas?? Or make calculations in an array and fill a range with calculations? What reason do you have for you method, Not saying its wrong just trying to understand why. Just seems like in the time you would take to fill the array you could be performing calculation (faster then letting the formulas calculate), OR that you could skip the array completely and just add formulas directly.

Comment: @user2140261, thank you. Yes, I do use this for real life proposes: user experience, for bypassing some security limitation when VBA is not allowed, or for auditing help. **First**, regarding your point to have the **value and not the formula**, I usually prefer the formula to see what the result means. If you audit a column called "Avg. Net Margin without commercial costs", what do you prefer: to have just the result value or the formula? (Will not easy to see if "financial disc." is part of "commercial costs", what is "net", what is used to weight the average, etc?).

Comment: **Second**, sometimes I simply multiple and very complex vlookup or nested sumif (or some times impossible vlookups) with "SUM" formulas to specifics cells (previously searched with VBA). This speed up later calculation if you want to make a sensibility analysis changing several parameters (but of course not the criteria used for searching cells with the VBA). Imagine 20.000 cells with complex sumif for picking just 1 to 10 cells of other 20.000 cells. Ok, maybe not the software for doing this, but no time and budget for evaluating other software for one time only and forget it after one week.

Comment: And finally, **Third**, for an optimization problem based on Excel (OpenSolver or What'sBest), I need to backup an matrix of formulas in an array while I'm performing VBA a sensibility analisys running OpenSolver several times. During and after the sensibility I have to restore the formulas back or change them to point to other cells depending on previous result. I checked several solution and the VBA array with formulas was the fastest for me (clean and simple also). @user2140261, hoping this three examples replies in part your doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your first code should work.
Instead of declaring it as string, declare it as variant.

So change your declaration from this:

```
Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String
```

to this:

```
Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As Variant
```

I have no way of trying it on Excel 2013, but it should work.
Hope it does.

Comment: +1 It works in Excel 2013. For type safety reasons I prefer to use the narrower type I plan to use. In this case string is the right type for handling an Excel formula. I don't like that VBA push my to use variant, but I suppose nothing to do in this case...

Comment: @L42, Thank you! It is very weird that the function #2 and #3 do work, in those cases Variant declaration is not needed (I can still use string declaration). Do you know why??

Comment: @A.Sommerh Function # 2 and #3 works because that is the default way of assigning a formula to a range. It accepts the string declaration because excel is really expecting the formula to be in string format. But when you pass array to a range like in Function #1, excel assumes that you want to preserve the array data type. Passing array to range is different from passing array element to range.

Comment: @L42 thank you, but still filling it is not consistent way. I can understand your argument when dealing with ".value" method, but why to preserve the array data type when using the ".function" method? I know this question has no answer, just speculation (probably not even the the original Microsoft team behind VBA know the reason why ;-) ). You don't need to reply this! Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I've never used this functionality before.

Your first one has the same result for me in both 2010 and 2013 - a column containing the string `"=1+2"`. I changed `FORML_ARRAY` from a string to a `Variant` and it works as expected. For good measure I changed the formula to include `i` and it still fills the range with formulas:

```
Sub AssignFormulas_1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As Variant 'changed to Variant
    For i = 1 To 1000
         FORML_ARRAY(i, 1) = "=" & i & "+2" 'changed 1 to i - still works
    Next i
    Range("A1:A1000").Formula = FORML_ARRAY
End Sub
```

Comment: @Doug, Thank you! It is very weird that the function #2 and #3 do work, in those cases Variant declaration is not needed (I can still use String declaration). Do you know why?? How do you figure out the solution for function #1 (prof and error)? You never tried before? Make some performance test, it really makes your VBA code fly when you have to work with a lot of cells!!

Comment: Although I haven't filled in formulas this way, I've done a lot with ranges and arrays, and, based on that experience, just figured a `Variant` would work. I tested it first in 2010 and then in 2013, with the same results for both.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option, cause as you said you would rather dim your array correctly, With this you can, it only adds 1/250th of a second to the **OVERALL** Sub 
(*not* per loop), but will allow you to dim your array as a string.

```
Sub AssignFormulas_2()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String

    For i = 1 To 1000
         FORML_ARRAY(i, 1) = "= " & i & " + 2"
    Next i

    Range("A1:A1000").Formula = FORML_ARRAY  '<- Don't work as formula
                                             '   It put the value!

    Range("A1:A1000").Value = Range("A1:A1000").Value
End Sub
```

Now, I am not sure why excel reads the strings as constants, But if you run your original formula and go to Evaluate Formula, it gives the error that the cell contains a constant, This really just seems to be a bug, but If i figure something else out I will edit my answer also.

***NOTE:*** This answer is not intended to be a BETTER answer as the accepted answer, it is a slower answer and is more of an alternative; to answer the request that you wanted to dim the array a string.

***UPDATE:*** This method will split the difference between the accepted answer and the above method. This will only add 1/500th of a second to the sub's run time.

```
Sub AssignFormulas_Transpose()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim FORML_ARRAY(1 To 1000) As String
    For i = 1 To 1000
         FORML_ARRAY(i) = "= " & i & " + 2"
    Next i

    Range("A1:A1000").Formula = Application.Transpose(FORML_ARRAY)  '<- Don't work as formula
                                                                    '   It put the value!
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but TextToColumns **will not work** for all the cases. If your formula text contains a "," or ";" it can split the formula to the cell of the right, breaking the solution. That is deal breaker for me.

Comment: Can you please replace your solution and use `Range("A1:A1000").value=Range("A1:A1000").value` instead of TextToColumns? It will make the trick of TextToColumns, don't split the formula in any case, and I believe is much more faster!

Comment: Updated the answer, That is much faster then TextToColumns , I was going to suggest setting TextToColumns by width by the max size of a cell, of delimit by no delimiter, but value is faster, and for the record it is only 1/250th of a second slower then using a variant array.

Comment: @A.Sommerh Added one more method, still not as fast as the accepted answer, but does still allow you to dim the array as a string array, and cuts the DIFFERENCE between my original method and the accepted method in half (its only 1/500th of a second slower then the accepted answer).

Comment: Good to have an additional method. Thank you! However, take some care: I just read that `Application.Transpose` has a limit on the quantity of elements (`5461` elements before Excel 2002, and 2^16, which is `65536` for Excel 2002, 2007 and 2010 when working with one dimensions array). **See #1:** [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/442358-limitations-transpose-visual-basic-applications.html) **See #2:** [link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/568747-solved-array-size-limit-when-using-worksheetfunction-transpose.html)